# Magento customer account edit form remove password

Tags: customer, customer-account

I want to change the edit form in the customer account, template `/app/design/frontend/theme/theme/template/customer/form/edit.phtml`

The current password is required to change the emailaddress and gender for example.
I want to remove this restriction, so that these details can be changed without the current password.

How can I remove this?

Comment: Are u solve this problem....?